# jquery if (css_attribute = value)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Is it possible to do an if statement in javascript/jquery to determine:

**If the value of a certain element's css attribute is equal to a given value?**

such as:

```
if( $('.box').css(background-color = blue) ){
    // do this...
}
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The [`css`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) JQuery method, when given only one parameter, will return the value for the given paramenter. You can try this:

```
var color = $('.box').css('background-color');
if (color == 'rgb(0, 0, 255)' || color == 'blue') // =='blue' <- IE hack
    alert("it's blue!\nColor detected: " + color);
```

The above sample will only work for the first element in the JQuery selector, therefore you should use the `.each` JQuery method to iterate through the whole selector if you have more than one element in it.

Please note that the `.css` JQuery method returns a RGB combination in most browsers (except IE), so testing it against a string such as `blue` will not suffice for non-IE browsers. You can test that in the [JQuery API site](http://api.jquery.com/css/) and [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6nj3q/6/).

And here's with the proper `.each` iteration:

```
$('.box').each(function(i){
    var color = $(this).css('background-color');
    if (color == 'rgb(0, 0, 255)' || color == 'blue') // =='blue' <- IE hack
        alert("div " + i + " is blue!\nColor detected: " + color);
});​
```

***[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6nj3q/6/)***

---

**Edit:** over a year and half later, I feel like this answer deserves an update.

For most use cases, I'd recommend using a CSS class:

```
.blue {
    color: blue;
}
```

This allows the usage of the [`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/), [`removeClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/), [`toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) methods for manipulation, as well as [`hasClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) for checking:

```
if ( $('#myElem').hasClass('blue') ) {
    //it has the .blue class!
}
```

This works seamlessly in all browsers without needing hacks, and as a plus you get better separation of concerns -- that is, if your styling ever changes, say `.blue { color: lightblue; }`, the JS will keep working without modifications.

Note: of course, this approach is not suitable for a couple rare use cases where the color value is dynamically generated (e.g. using `Math.random()` or picking a color value off a canvas pixel), in these rare use cases you can still use the first solution in this answer.

Comment: Or like this `$($('.box')[3]).css()` to choose the *fourth* element that matches.

Comment: Added RGB note, `.each` iteration and example.

Comment: Thanks! Perfect answer, and you saved me trouble of messing around with HEX values instead of RGB too.

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
if ($('.box').css('background-color') === 'blue') 
{// do this...}
```

Comment: In this case `===` and `==` are essentially going to give the same result. It's a matter of preference, but both are correct.

Comment: strictly equal to string `blue`? Testing the `.css` method in the [API page](http://api.jquery.com/css/) seems to always return a RGB string.. edit: Except on IE.

Answer (score 2):

check for spaces in

```
if($(this).css('color') == 'rgb(251, 176, 64)')
```

"SPACE AFTER COMA"

Comment: This returns true for me even if the link is red. My :visited color is green.

Answer (score 0):

```
boxes = $('.box');
for(var i = 0;i<boxes.length;i++) {
  if(boxes[i].style.backgroundColor =="blue") {
    //do stuff
  }
}
```

Comment: Note: The question is about `jQuery`.

Answer (score 0):

None of the above seems to work here in 2015. Testing a link's color against the :visited color seems to be true in all cases in Chrome for me. Also if you are not 'sniffing' and genuinely want to know if a link has been clicked during their visit to YOUR website I've found that a simple:

```
$("a").addClass('visited');
```

and checking for the class works just fine.

```
if ( $("a").hasClass('visited'); ){ console.log('do something honorable'); }
```